# Creating functions in MatLab through excel sheets

Tags: excel, matlab

This is really simple, and for some reason I am having a ton of difficulty doing this.  Suppose I have an excel file: "Data.xls"  I can do:

```
a = xlsread('Data.xls','Sheet1','A1:B10');
```

And i get the data I want.  However, I want to write a function to do this:

```
`function [ data ] = ReadData( fileID,Sheet,Lines )

data = xlsread('fileID','Sheet','Lines');

end
```

And when  I run `ReadData('Data.xls','Sheet1','A1:B10')`

I get

`??? Attempt to reference field of
non-structure array.`

So I am wondering what is the proper way to do this in a function?

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're getting that particular error. However, when you do this:

```
fileID = 'Data.xls';
Sheet = 'Sheet1';
Lines = 'A1:B10';
data = xlsread(fileID,Sheet,Lines);
```

Then you are passing those variables into the function, and you shouldn't surround them with ''.

fileID = the string variable, 'Data.xls'

'fileID' = a string which contains the text 'fileID', and has no connection to the file you're trying to open.